# Problemas de Relação entre "Tabela" e Usuario Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-queryset

Estou trabalhando com Django para desenvolvimento de uma aplicação para um Help Desk, tenho a seguinte situação:

Tenho uma tabela com nome "Unidade" que será a tabela responsável por separar meu sistemas em 4 ou mais unidades.

Meu problema é, que os usuários precisam estar associados a uma unidade através de uma chave estrangeira. Porém não estou encontrando uma forma de fazer esta associação.

Eu consigo "linkar" cada unidade a um usuário se eu cadastrar o usuário, depois atualizar o cadastro selecionando as unidades, mas no formulário de cadastro também aparecem as unidades para serem selecionadas, elas vão até a view pelo POST, mas não se associam ao usuário depois do save.

Meus modelos Unidade e User

```py
# arquivo: core.models.py

class Unidade(models.Model):

    nome = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    endereco = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    telefone = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Unidades"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, models.Model):

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sobrenome = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    nascimento = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    unidade = models.ManyToManyField('Unidade')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return f"{self.nome} {self.sobrenome}"

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.nome

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

Meus forms para criação e atualização de usuários.

```py
# arquivo: accounts.forms.py

User = get_user_model()

class SignupUserForm(UserCreationForm, forms.Form):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('nome', 'sobrenome', 'email', 'nascimento', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_admin',
                  'password1', 'password2', 'unidade')
        widgets = {
            'nome': forms.TextInput(attrs={'type':'text'}),
            'sobrenome': forms.TextInput(attrs={'type':'text'}),
            'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'col-12', 'type':'email', 'placeholder':'Digite seu e-mail'}),
            'nascimento': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'col-10'}, format='%d/%m/%Y'),
            'unidade': forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class':'col-12'})
        }

class UpdateUserForm(UserChangeForm, forms.Form):    

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('nome', 'sobrenome', 'email', 'nascimento', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_admin',
                  'unidade')
        widgets = {
            'nome': forms.TextInput(attrs={'type':'text'}),
            'sobrenome': forms.TextInput(attrs={'type':'text'}),
            'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'col-12', 'type':'email', 'placeholder':'Digite seu e-mail'}),
            'nascimento': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'col-10'}, format='%d/%m/%Y'),
            'unidade': forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class':'col-12'})
        }
```

Minhas views para renderizar a pagina e processar o formulário.

```py
# arquivo: accounts.views.py

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from accounts.forms import SignupUserForm, UpdateUserForm
from core.models import User


@login_required
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.is_admin:
            form = SignupUserForm(request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('/usuarios')
        else:
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        if not request.user.is_admin:
            return redirect('/')
        form = SignupUserForm()
    template_name = 'registration/register.html'
    return render(request, template_name, {'form':form})

@login_required
def updateuser(request, id):
    template_name = 'registration/atualizar.html'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        usuario = get_object_or_404(User, pk=id)
        form = UpdateUserForm(request.POST, instance=usuario)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/usuarios')
        else:
            return render(request, template_name, {'error':form.errors, 'form': form})
    else:
        usuario = get_object_or_404(User, pk=id)
        form = UpdateUserForm(instance=usuario)
        return render(request, template_name, {'form':form})
```

Meu template

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Cadastro de Usuários - Django Desk{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<style type="text/css">
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        background-color: #F4F4F4;
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 6px;
        background: #F4F4F4;
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background: #dad7d7;
    }
    .selectmultiple {
        width: 800px !important;
    }
</style>

<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item" aria-current="page"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item" aria-current="page">
            <a href="/usuarios">Usuários</a>
        </li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Cadastro</li>
    </ol>
</nav>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-6">
        <form method="POST">
            <div class="h4 text-center">Cadastro - DjangoDesk</div>
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{next}}">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                        {{ form.nome|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                        {{ form.sobrenome|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                {{ form.email|as_crispy_field }}
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                        {{ form.nascimento|as_crispy_field }}
                        <small id="passwordHelpBlock" class="form-text text-muted">
                            Seguir o formato <span class="font-italic">"dia/mês/ano"</span>
                        </small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                        {{ form.is_active|as_crispy_field }}
                        {{ form.is_staff|as_crispy_field }}
                        {{ form.is_admin|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                        {{ form.password1|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                        {{ form.password2|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                {{ form.unidade|as_crispy_field }}
            <input type="submit" value="Entrar" class="btn btn-primary">
        </form>
     </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Template de visualização:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Lista de Usuários - Django Desk{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item" aria-current="page"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item" aria-current="page"><a href="/usuarios">Usuarios</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Visualizar Usuário</li>
    </ol>
</nav>
<div class="row">
    <table class="table table-responsive talbe-bordered">
        {% if usuario %}
        <tr>
            <td>Nome completo:</td>
            <td>{{usuario.get_full_name}}</td>
            <td>Ativo:</td>
            <td>
                {% if usuario.is_active %}
                    <span class="text-success ml-3"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i></span>
                {% else %}
                    <span class="text-danger ml-3"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></span>
                {% endif %}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>E-mail:</td>
            <td>{{usuario.email}}</td>
            <td>Gestor:</td>
            <td>
                {% if usuario.is_staff %}
                    <span class="text-success ml-3"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i></span>
                {% else %}
                    <span class="text-danger ml-3"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></span>
                {% endif %}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data de Nascimento:</td>
            <td>{{usuario.nascimento}}</td>
            <td>Administrador:</td>
            <td>
                {% if usuario.is_admin %}
                    <span class="text-success ml-3"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i></span>
                {% else %}
                    <span class="text-danger ml-3"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></span>
                {% endif %}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr-border">
            <td>Unidades:</td>
            <td>
                {% if usuario.unidade.all %}
                    <ul>
                        {% for unidade in usuario.unidade.all %}
                            <li>{{unidade}}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                {% endif %}
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endif %}
    </table>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Todo formulário funciona, consigo cadastrar usuários, consigo atualizar os usuários, apenas esse simples campo `unidade` que no cadastro na minha pagina de visualização dos usuários não mostra nenhuma informação, apenas depois de eu atualizar o cadastro do usuário selecionando novamente as unidades.

Alguém sabe o que pode causar isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, sou iniciante no Django então me perdoarei por cometer esses erros banais. Mas achei a resposta. Acontece que o Django quando utiliza o `form.save(commit=False)` ele não salva o que estiver relacionado como 'ManyToManyField', neste caso precisa utilizar o `form.save_m2m()` logo depois do `form.save()`, mas antes é necessário utilizar o `form.save(commit=False)`. Abaixo a solução do meu problema no arquivo `accounts/views.py`:

```py
# arquivo: accounts/views.py

@login_required
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.is_admin:
            form = SignupUserForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                obj = form.save(commit=False) # Esta adição.
                obj.save() # Está adição
                form.save_m2m() # e Esta adição, fizeram toda a diferença nos resultados.
                return redirect('/usuarios')
        else:
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        if not request.user.is_admin:
            return redirect('/')
        form = SignupUserForm()
    template_name = 'registration/register.html'
    return render(request, template_name, {'form':form})
```